# "На самолёте" или "самолётом"?

Tags: лексика

Как правильно говорить: "лететь самолётом" или "на самолёте"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специального правила на этот счет найти не удалось, но логично будет предположить, что ездить можно НА чем-то, либо пользоваться чем-то. То есть, можно сказать *"лететь на самолете"*, либо *"пользоваться самолетом"*.